# Is there a way to automatically answer a dialog box using formula coding?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula, domino-designer-eclipse

Is there a way to automatically answer a dialog box using formula coding? In IBM notes domino - I would like to have some formula code behind a button to automatically answer a dialog box. Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of dialog box is it? Who/what executes the dialog box?

Comment: @KnutHerrmann Basically I have a button that has formula behind it where it saves it and takes it out of edit mode, but for some odd reason a dialog box appears saying "would you like to save?" I would just like either this dialog box to not appear or automatically say yes

Comment: you really have to REWRITE your question !
The response with your new comment is:
add in your code : FIELD SAVEOPTIONS:="0" if you want to automatically close the doc WITHOUT saving (look for other options of SaveOptions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid the "would you like to save?" dialog box.

Save your document *after* you changed all fields in your button.

```
@Command([EditDocument]; 1); 
FIELD Counter := Counter + 1;     
@PostedCommand([FileSave]);
@PostedCommand([EditDocument]; 0);
```

Comment: @Command([EditDocument];"1");
FIELD Counter := Counter + 1;
@Command([FileSave]);
@Command([EditDocument];"0");                                                                    Is what I already have.... Because I need to go into edit mode to actually click on the button for the counter to work. so this isn't working for me so far

Comment: Work with `@PostedCommand`. They get executed after `@Command`s.

Answer (score -1):

you really have to REWRITE your question which is unclear!

The response with your new comment is:

add in your code : `FIELD SAVEOPTIONS:="0"` if you want to automatically close the doc WITHOUT saving (look for other options of SaveOptions)

If you have Lotus script code look at [The third SaveOptions value, or How to suppress the "Do you want to save this document?" message box in Notes](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/The_third_SaveOptions_value_or_How_to_suppress_the_Do_you_want_to_save_this_document_message_box_in_Notes)